# Link1104 cannot open file tbb_debug.lib

Tags: c++

I tried to adjust the tbb library for c++ on visual studio 2013 ultimate. but I get the error above. I have made the following adjustments:

1. > Go to [Project] ! [ Your Application i Properties] ! [Debugging] ! [Environment]
   >     PATH=%PATH%;C:\multi-core pr\tbb42_20140122oss_osx_0\tbb42_20140122oss\bin
2. > [Project]  [ Your Application i Properties] --- C/C++----General---additional
   >       directories
   >      C:\multi-core pr\tbb42_20140122oss_osx_0\tbb42_20140122oss\include
3. > [Project]  [ Your Application i Properties] --- Linker----General--Additional 
   >       library dependencies
   >       C:\multi-core pr\tbb42_20140122oss_osx_0\tbb42_20140122oss\lib\
4. > [Project]  [ Your Application i Properties] ---Input ----additional dependcies
   >        tbb_debug.lib;

But it doesn't work. Could you please help me?

Comment: The path contains spaces, you have to put "double quotes" around it.  And you have to use the right setting, Linker + General + Additional Library Directories.  Building with an OSX version of a library in VS2013 doesn't sound like a lot of happiness ahead either.

Comment: "Building with an OSX version of a library in VS2013 doesn't sound like a lot of happiness" what's your suggestion then?